# Focuspoint Extension with bootstrap_package on TYPO3 8.7.4

Tags: typo3

Is it possible to use the focuspoint extension correct with bootstrap_package on TYPO3 8.7.4 ?

https://typo3.org/extensions/repository/view/focuspoint

The Focuspoint Ext. works in Images to set Focuspoint, it can be included in Template but on Page when i use a ratio like 1:1 or something (4:3, 16:9) it will not show the ratio in Frontend.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot speak for the `focuspoint` extension but TYPO3 ships with support for crop variants, focus areas and cover areas since version 8, you should have a look:

https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TCAReference/ColumnsConfig/Type/ImageManipulation.html#cropvariants

Comment: thanks, but the TYPO3 image crop is not linking to the original Image, only to the cropped image. I would it use for a simple lightbox link - in lightbox i would like show the orginal image. I found no answer on this problem so i'm lookin out for another solution. So i found Focuspoint..